# Clarify on slice categories

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf C$ be a category and, for an object $c$, consider the slice category $\mathbf C/c$. While finding the subobject classifier of $\mathbf C/c$ (assuming that $\mathbf C$ has one), I proved the following: an arrow in $\mathbf C/c$ is monic iff it is monic as an arrow of $\mathbf C$; a square in $\mathbf C/c$ is cartesian iff it is in $\mathbf C$. These facts are true because the definitions of mono and pullback rely on arrows with fixed codomain only (i.e. they don't mention arrows with fixed domain), and the arrows of $\mathbf C/c$ with codomain $c'$ are all the arrows in  $\mathbf C$ with codomain $c'$.

*Is there a more formal/general way to say that, if a diagram in $\mathbf C/c$ has a certain property, that can be expressed mentioning arrows with fixed codomain only, then the diagram has that property also in $\mathbf C$?*

What I said doesn't make completely sense, because I don't think that a property of a diagram in $\mathbf C/c$, stated in $\mathbf C$ (viewing the diagram as a diagram in $\mathbf C$) makes always sense; but as I said, I wouldn't know how to make it more rigorous, so I hope that the context in the first paragraph will give you an idea of what I mean. Surely a consequence is that the limit of a diagram in $\mathbf C/c$ is the limit of that diagram in $\mathbf C$, but for example the property of an arrow being monic cannot be expressed by limits (right?). Thank you

Comment: For the case of the slice category, it's a property of the forgetful functor $U : {\bf C}/c \to \bf C$: it creates colimits (and connected limits, iirc? I might be wrong).

Comment: Also, the property of an arro being monic *can* be expressed as a limit property: $m : A\to B$ is monic if and only if the square 
$\begin{array}{ccc}
A &=& A \\
|| && \downarrow \\
A &\to& B \end{array}$ is a pullback.